# Downloading mail from hotmail

Tags: ssl, rebol, hotmail

I want to script the download of messages from hotmail.

Both Gmail and Hotmail allow access by secure POP on port 995.

My script works fine with Gmail ... but after I send the line to Hotmail

USER myliveaccount@hotmail.com

I don't get a response back.

I installed Windows Live Mail and that is clearly able to download my hotmail messages.

1. Is there a way to trace SSL so I can see what I am doing wrong?
2. Is hotmail expecting something else apart from the USER message from the client?

This is sample code from the REBOL shell.

```
>> pop: open/lines ssl://pop3.live.com:995
>> set-modes pop [secure: true]
>> pick pop 1
== "+OK BLU0-POP295 POP3 server ready"
>> insert pop "USER myliveaccount@hotmail.com"
>> pick pop 1 
== none
```

Comment: post some of the source code you are using to talk to the server...

Comment: >> pop: open/lines ssl://pop3.live.com:995
>> set-modes pop [secure: true]
>> pick pop 1
== "+OK BLU0-POP295 POP3 server ready"
>> insert pop "USER myliveaccount@hotmail.com"
>> pick pop 1
== none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a rebol expert but you may need to include \r\n at the end of USER command line in order to notify the POP server that you're done sending input. I'd guess the server is still waiting for you to send more information or end the line.

Comment: I think you're right.  open/lines is supposed to handle this transparently but it looks as though it is only sending a LF.  I'll have to send a bug report to rebol.com

Comment: insert pop "USER myliveaccount@hotmail.com^M"

works as REBOL then adds the LF after this.

Comment: forgot to mention that the secure pop protocol for Rebol2 can be downloaded from http://compkarori.co.nz:8090/REBOL_stuff/REBOL_2/Secure_POP_and_SMTP